# Update a record by appending data to a column in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table that has three columns (`char(14)`, `char(20)`, `text`) the first column is a fk to the parent and it is part on a select statement. I need all of the rows in that table to be on one row in the results. The database is SQL Server 2000 and I can only read the data I can't modify the database.

So basically I want to do the script below but in SQL Server 2000

```
   Select Parent.col1,
     (
       SELECT rtrim(child.col1) + '-' + cast(child.col2 as varchar(8000)) + ' '  AS [text()] 
         FROM child
         where child.FK = Parent.PK
         FOR XML) as OneRow,
    Parent.col2,
    Parent.col3 
    From Parent
      Join child on child.fk = Parent.PK
```

Comment: LOok up the writetext and updatetext commands in Books Online

Comment: can you remind me which of the above is missing in SQL2000? Is it FOR XML clause?

Comment: how many rows need to be processed? how often is this going to be called? You could write a cursor, but watch out with those...